# Multiply two matrices in Matlab to obtain 3-dimensional matrix

Tags: matlab

I have two sparse matrices in Matlab, `A` and `B`,
and I want to compute a three-dimensional matrix `C` such that

```
C(i,j,k) = A(i,j) * B(j,k)
```

can I do this without a loop?

(Side question: Is there a name for this operation?)

Edit:
Seems my question has already been asked (just for full matrices):
[Create a 3-dim matrix from two 2-dim matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16353522/create-a-3-dim-matrix-from-two-2-dim-matrices?rq=1)

Comment: I am curious on the context in which you needed your hash join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **full** matrices:

You can do it using [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) and [`shiftdim`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/shiftdim.html):

```
C = bsxfun(@times, A, shiftdim(B,-1))
```

*Explanation*: Let `A` be of size M x N and `B` of size N x P. Applying `shiftdim(B,-1)` gives a 1 x N x P array. `bsxfun` implicitly replicates `A` along the third dimension and `shiftdim(B,-1)` along the first to compute the desired element-wise product.

Another possibility, usually [*less efficient*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382654/matlabs-bsxfun-code) than `bsxfun`,  is to repeat the arrays explicity along the desired dimensions, using [`repmat`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html):

```
C = repmat(A, [1 1 size(B,2)]) .* repmat(shiftdim(B,-1), [size(A,1) 1 1])
```

---

For **sparse** matrices:

The result cannot be sparse, as sparse ND-arrays are not supported.. But you can do the computations with sparse `A` and `B` using [linear indexing](http://www.mathworks.es/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html):

```
ind1 = repmat(1:numel(A),1,size(B,2));
ind2 = repmat(1:numel(B),size(A,1),1);
ind2 = ind2(:).';
C = NaN([size(A,1),size(A,2),size(B,2)]); %// preallocate with appropriate shape
C(:) = full(A(ind1).*B(ind2)); %// need to use full if C is to be 3D
```

Comment: Is it possible to modify the version with `bsxfun` and `shiftdim` to work for sparse matrices?

Comment: I hadn't thought of that... No, it seems it doesn't work with sparse matrices. You would need something like `bsxfun(@times, full(A), shiftdim(full(B),-1))`

Comment: Maybe I was a bit too fast when asking the question. It seems that Matlab per default does not even support 3-dimensional sparse matrices. I have to admit that currently I am using something like `A(i+m*(j-1),k) = B(i,j) * C(j,k)` and was optimistically assuming to be able to change it to `A(i,j,k)`.

Comment: @Matthias009 See updated answer. You can do the computations on sparse A and B, but as you say the result has to be full

Comment: The linear indexing solution looks interesting, probably thats the way to go for me. (Just somehow work with `C = A(ind1).*B(idnd2)` directly). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your side question: the name for this operation is a [hash join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_join).